# Web site with java application without java EE

Tags: java

Is it possible to make a web site with an ordinary java application (without JavaEE). Where the main class is with method

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {..}
```

I'm unable to do dynamic web application, while many days i tried. Jetty, Java EE is too much dificult and i cannot reach forward errors like "error 404", etc.

Comment: What do you think Java EE is?

Comment: Have you tried Spring Boot (http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)? Technically, it still uses Jetty, Tomcat or Undertow as a web server, but Spring Boot hides many of the configuration details of the web server and gives you something along the lines of what you are asking. Ultimately, you do need a web server to listen to HTTP requests on a port, so either you use an existing web server technology (as the one provided by a JEE or servlet container for Java) or write your own socket listener. The latter is unnecessarily complex and redundant given what Java already offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are confuse over the usage of Java EE and Java SE terminologies. Just because EE expands to Enterprise Edition, it does not mean that it is used only by enterprises.

Java EE is a set of specifications that are bundled together to form a platform. If you need to develop a web application, then you need to use atleast Servlets and JSP specifications which are subsets of the Java EE specification.

Comment: That Spring Boots requires an Spring Framework. I mean is it existing an one jar file, where is all necessary web developing thing and that can be used with an java class containing public static void main(String[] arg) method?

Comment: I will highly recommend you to study about JavaEE and its architecture from any good srouce or from oracle doc (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhqt.html) When you get familiar then look into spring framework from `https://spring.io` and study its docs. Spring is a framework just, in easy words it is bundle of libraries with prebuild of functionalities that make life easier.

Comment: I looked the javaee the spring several times, but simple problem. In eclipse these technologies don't work. I'm looking for ONE JAR library by using main method.

Comment: if have problem with configuration of Spring with Eclipse then go to https://spring.io/tools/eclipse and download your OS perspective pre-configured zip file. or you can install it from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse into your previous eclipse

Comment: no no. I mean a standard eclipse, but no spring, no maven, no ant and no other technologies. I'm looking for a clean java and special one jar file for helping to web  or mobile applications.